# Use of undeclared identifier and expected expression error. Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, expression, identifier

So I am completely new to C++ and attempting to use Xcode to write this code that analyzes two integers. I keep getting an error on the "if" line that says "use of undeclared identifier x, and "use of undeclared identifier y" I also get an error on the "else" line that says "Expected expression". What do I need to do/change to make this program work? Help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap (int &x, int &y);

int main()
{ 
    cout << "Please enter two integers:/n";
    cout << "First integer ==> " " >> x >> ";
    cout << "Second integer ==> " " >> y >> ";
    cout << endl;

    if ( &x < &y )
        cout << "Your integers are in the correct order:/n";

    cout << " << x << " " << y << ";

    else void swap(int &x, int &y);

    cout << "Your integers have been swapped:/n";
    cout << " << x << " " << y << ";
}
```

Comment: FYI if you have multi-line `if-else` statements you need to use curly braces `{}` to specify what lines are wrapped in those clauses.

Comment: Many things that need to be fixed.  No declaration of x and y (as the error message said), you're printing x and y , but you haven't set the value of x and y, if statement is comparing the addresses of x and y (not the contents), missing sets of braces, call to swap function is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The variables `x` and `y` do not exist in the scope of the function `main`.

You just declared those variables in the function declaration `swap`, and happen to name those variables `x` and `y`. That's what these errors mean. The variables do not exist in the current scope.

```
use of undeclared identifier x
use of undeclared identifier y
```

You also do not ever define that function, so you are likely name-shadowing the `std` version of `swap`.

Comment: Not shadowing, overloading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare and assign x and y inside a function (or outside) that refers to the values:

for example

```
int main()
{ 
    int x = 5, y = 10;

    if ( &x < &y )
        cout << "Your integers are in the correct order:/n";

    cout << " << x << " " << y << ";

    else void swap(int &x, int &y);

   //...
}
```

edit:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap (int &x, int &y);

int main()
{ 
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    cout << "Please enter two integers:/n";
    cout << "First integer ==> " " >> x >> ";
    cout << "Second integer ==> " " >> y >> ";
    cout << endl;

    if ( x < y )
    {
        cout << "Your integers are in the correct order:/n";

        cout << " << x << " " << y << ";
    }

    else
    {
         swap(int &x, int &y);

         cout << "Your integers have been swapped:/n";
         cout << " << x << " " << y << ";
    }
    return 0;
}


void swap (int &x, int &y)
{
     // define here
}
```

Comment: You need to enclose your 'if else' into blocks with curly braces and also call the swap function inside the main function, (you have instead declared it)